# Change the link text in a show/hide function

Tags: javascript

Ok so I have been wrestling with this and now thought I ask for a little help.

I have two paragraphs with the id's show1 and show2.

I have a short text to each one that should expand upon click of a link above them.

My function works to expand and to collapse but it feels like it does not get the value of the link, to be more exact, the link text because I get "link is null".

It works all the way down to var status and innerHTML, if I comment out those two lines it works, well it does not change my link text from show to hide... So if any kind soul could help me out it would be much appreciated.

```
/* Function created by "Simon Willson" to be able to 
call several functions with a single event */

//Create the function
function addLoadEvent(func) {
//Create a variable for window.onload event
var oldonload = window.onload;
//If window.onload is NOT a function, then assign 'func' to window.onload
if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
//If window.onload already is a function then make a new function
} else {
    window.onload = function() {
    //To do what the old onload function did
    if (oldonload) {
    oldonload();
    }
    //then do whatever the new function does 
    func();
    }
}
}

function newLink() {
    //Make a few safety check to see if the browser can handle the elements
    if (!document.getElementById) {
        if (!document.createElememt) {
            if (!document.createTextNode) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    //Create the link
    newLinkElement = document.createElement('a');
    //Give the link a Id
    newLinkElement.id = 'show1_link';
    //Set the href
    newLinkElement.href = "javascript:showHide(this.id,'show1')";
    //Create a variable for the link text
    var linkText = document.createTextNode('Visa mera information');
    //Append the text to the link
    newLinkElement.appendChild(linkText);
    //Create a variable for the paragraph
    var elem = document.getElementById('show1')
    //Insert the text before the paragraph with the Id show1
    elem.parentNode.insertBefore(newLinkElement,show1);
}
addLoadEvent(newLink);

function showHide(link_id,elemId) {
    var link = document.getElementById(link_id);
    var text = document.getElementById(elemId);
    text.style.display = (text.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    var status = (text.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    text.style.display = status;
    link.innerHTML = (status == 'block') ? 'Dölj information' : 'Visa mera information';
}
```

Comment: [Can you show a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we can work with?

Comment: Edited the Javascript to include the addLoadEvent function, the page is offline so... It's a basic html document with two paragraphs p class="show" id="show1" 2nd id is "show2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with both your code examples but ended up doing

```
//Create the function
function addLoadEvent(func) {
//Create a variable for window.onload event
var oldonload = window.onload;
//If window.onload is NOT a function, then assign 'func' to window.onload
if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
//If window.onload already is a function then make a new function
} else {
    window.onload = function() {
    //To do what the old onload function did
    if (oldonload) {
    oldonload();
    }
    //then do whatever the new function does 
    func();
    }
}
}
//Add as many functions you like with addLoadEvent(functionName);


/* Create the object hideParagraph, showOrHide using singleton
method, this way the instance only occur once and not globaly, 
then called using (function()ObjName.functionName('classNameHere'));*/

//Create the global variable
var hideParagraph = {
//Create the private function for the hidden function
hideText: function() {
    //Make a few safety checks to see if the browser can understand the code
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName) {
        if (!document.getAttribute) {
        return false;
        }
    }
    //Make a variable to get tag names with a wildcard
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    //Make the loop
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        //If it belongs to the class show
        if (elements[i].getAttribute('class') == 'show') {
        //Then hide it
        elements[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
}
addLoadEvent(hideParagraph.hideText);


//Create the global variable
var showOrHide = {
//Create the private function for the link
createLinks: function(nodeClass) {
    //Make a few safety checks to see if the browser can understand the code
    if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
        if (!target.parentNode) {
            if (!document.createElement) {
            return false;
            }
        }
    }
    //Get all the nodes of a class
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName(nodeClass);
    //Make the loop
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) (function(i) {
        //Make a variable for the nodes
        var target = nodes[i];
        //Create the link element
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        //Prevent the page from ever refeshing on click
        a.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
        //Set the link text
        a.innerHTML = 'Visa mera information';
        //Set the click function for the link
        a.onclick = function() {
            /* Call the global variable showOrHide with the function     showHide 
                using this link and it's target, the variable we made for nodes[i] */
            showOrHide.showHide(this, target);
        }
        //Get the parent node, in this case the parent is 'post'
        var parent = target.parentNode;
        /* Insert the link (a) before it's target (nodes[i]) element, the target
            node, the node is set when you call the function */
        parent.insertBefore(a, target);
    //Close the loop and then close up and end with the function name (i)
    })(i);
/* Close the createLinks function and after put a punctuation mark , 
    that mark separates one function from another in a singleton method */
},
//Another private function
showHide: function(trigger, target) {
    //Set the toggle option
    var status = (target.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    //Depending on what the status is
    target.style.display = status;
    //Change the link text accordingly
    trigger.innerHTML = (status == 'block') ? 'Dölj information' : 'Visa mera information';
}
}
addLoadEvent(function() { showOrHide.createLinks('show')});
```

Thought I share my complete and working code example for hiding as many paragraphs you want with one class and then loop through and make as many links as you have paragraph with the class you define yourself, then position them above that element. Everything is using singleton method except the first addLoadEvent script, maybe it will help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

In your function showHide:

```
function showHide(link_id,elemId) {
    var link = document.getElementById(link_id);
    var text = document.getElementById(elemId);
  //  text.style.display = (text.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    var status = (text.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    text.style.display = status;
    link.innerHTML = (status == 'block') ? 'Dölj information' : 'Visa mera information';
}
```

Your are setting text.style.display twice. Remove the line I show commented above.

I would probably write this as follows :

```
function showHide (linkEl, textEl) {
  var status;
  typeof linkEl === 'string' && (linkEl = document.getElementById (linkEl));
  typeof textEl === 'string' && (textEl = document.getElementById (textEl));

  if (textEl) {
    textEl.style.display = (status = (textEl.style.display === 'block')) ? 
                             'none' : 'block';
    linkEl && (linkEl.innerHTML = status ? 
                             'Dölj information' : 'Visa mera information');
  }
}
```

This allows you to call showHide with either the id's of the elements or the elements themselves. It also checks for the presence of the elements and does nothing if they are not found.

See http://jsfiddle.net/CgnXL/ for a fully worked example